# Guaranteeing the same subset for several techniques in Rapidminer's X-Validation

Tags: validation, data-mining, rapidminer, cross-validation

I am in the feature selection stage of a class data mining project, the main objective of it is to compare several data mining techniques (Naive Baiyes, SVM,etc...). In this stage I am using a wrapper with X-Validation,like in the example below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<process version="5.3.008">
  <context>
    <input/>
    <output/>
    <macros/>
  </context>
  <operator activated="true" class="process" compatibility="5.3.008" expanded="true" name="Process">
    <process expanded="true">
      <operator activated="true" class="optimize_selection" compatibility="5.3.008" expanded="true" height="94" name="Optimize Selection (3)" width="90" x="179" y="120">
        <parameter key="generations_without_improval" value="100"/>
        <parameter key="limit_number_of_generations" value="true"/>
        <parameter key="maximum_number_of_generations" value="-1"/>
        <process expanded="true">
          <operator activated="true" class="x_validation" compatibility="5.3.008" expanded="true" height="112" name="Validation" width="90" x="179" y="75">
            <process expanded="true">
              <operator activated="true" class="naive_bayes" compatibility="5.3.008" expanded="true" height="76" name="Naive Bayes (4)" width="90" x="119" y="30"/>
              <connect from_port="training" to_op="Naive Bayes (4)" to_port="training set"/>
              <connect from_op="Naive Bayes (4)" from_port="model" to_port="model"/>
              <portSpacing port="source_training" spacing="0"/>
              <portSpacing port="sink_model" spacing="0"/>
              <portSpacing port="sink_through 1" spacing="0"/>
            </process>
            <process expanded="true">
              <operator activated="true" class="apply_model" compatibility="5.3.008" expanded="true" height="76" name="Apply Model (8)" width="90" x="45" y="30">
                <list key="application_parameters"/>
              </operator>
              <operator activated="true" class="performance" compatibility="5.3.008" expanded="true" height="76" name="Performance (8)" width="90" x="209" y="30"/>
              <connect from_port="model" to_op="Apply Model (8)" to_port="model"/>
              <connect from_port="test set" to_op="Apply Model (8)" to_port="unlabelled data"/>
              <connect from_op="Apply Model (8)" from_port="labelled data" to_op="Performance (8)" to_port="labelled data"/>
              <connect from_op="Performance (8)" from_port="performance" to_port="averagable 1"/>
              <portSpacing port="source_model" spacing="0"/>
              <portSpacing port="source_test set" spacing="0"/>
              <portSpacing port="source_through 1" spacing="0"/>
              <portSpacing port="sink_averagable 1" spacing="0"/>
              <portSpacing port="sink_averagable 2" spacing="0"/>
            </process>
          </operator>
          <connect from_port="example set" to_op="Validation" to_port="training"/>
          <connect from_op="Validation" from_port="averagable 1" to_port="performance"/>
          <portSpacing port="source_example set" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="source_through 1" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_performance" spacing="0"/>
        </process>
      </operator>
      <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 1" spacing="0"/>
    </process>
  </operator>
</process>
```

The issue is that if I want to compare the several techniques I must guarantee that the sets generated in the Cross Validation phase are identical for all the techniques so that I know the accuracy of the results generated were made under the exact same conditions. However inside the X-Validation operator I can't put more than one model creating operator, so I don't know how to guarantee that.

Answer (score 0):

The `Optimize Selection` operator uses the performance of the inner operators to determine which attributes to retain or remove during forward or backward selection. This means the attribute order will be determined by the performance returned by the inner learner. A different inner learner will yield a different ordering in general. If this is what you want to do then it would be possible to take a copy of the example set inside the `Optimize Selection` operator using the `Multiply` operator and pass this to another validation block containing the other learner. You could then use the `Log` operator to record performance values for this learner and the original one that is driving the attribute ordering. The `Optimize Selection` operator also can have its progress logged and it is possible to record the feature names currently being considered.

Comment: I see what you mean. But inside the Optimize Selection, we have the x-validation to evaluate the performance, if I decide to have k subsets in the x-validation is there any guarantee that the inner learner will have the same k subsets generated by the x-validation?

Comment: You can set the random number seed for the `X-Validation` operator. This might have the desired effect by selecting the same rows within folds each time. Cross validation is only estimating  what the performance might be. The model it uses is based on 90% of the data and the assumption is made that this is close enough to the final model when 10 different 90% model performances are averaged.